# Is it possible to perform an INSERT operation with the GROUP BY clause in SPARQL/Update?

Tags: sparql, rdf, blazegraph, knowledge-graph

Suppose I have a graph containing students from three different grades.

Sample graph:

```
<http://some/graph#John_Doe> rdf:type <http://some/graph/ontology#Student>
<http://some/graph#John_Doe> <http://some/graph#hasGrade> <http://some/graph#Grade_3>
<http://some/graph#Grade_3> rdf:type <http://some/graph/ontology#Grade>
```

I want to create an attribute for every instance of class ***Grade*** called ***gradeStrength*** to store the number of students in that grade.

With the above example it would look like:

```
<http://some/graph#Grade_3> <http://some/graph#gradeStrength> 1^^xsd:integer
```

Currently I do it using two separate queries as follows -

1. Run a SELECT + GROUP BY query on the graph to get count per grade
2. Iterate over the result rows of 1. to create a string of triples
3. Run a INSERT DATA update query on the graph

How can I achieve this by using a single SPARQL/Update query using the INSERT and GROUP BY constructs? I tried writing such a query and it fails in Blazegraph.

Comment: yes, that is possible. Use `INSERT {?grade <http://some/graph#gradeStrength> ?gradeStrength} WHERE { { SELECT ?grade (COUNT(?student) AS ?gradeStrength)  { ?student  <http://some/graph#hasGrade> ?grade} GROUP BY ?grade   } }` - (untested indeed)

Comment: @UninformedUser I tested it with the sample data above and the update query you suggested on blazegraph and it worked! Thank you. First question on stackoverflow - not sure how to accept this as an answer and close the question.

Comment: You can simply add the working query as an answer and also click on accept for your own answer. This will basically mark the question as resolved then, there is no proper "close"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
INSERT {
  ?grade <http://some/graph#gradeStrength> ?gradeStrength
} 
WHERE 
{ 
  { 
    SELECT ?grade (COUNT(?student) AS ?gradeStrength)  
    { 
      ?student  <http://some/graph#hasGrade> ?grade . 
    } 
    GROUP BY ?grade   
  } 
}
```

Answer made from comment by @UninformedUser. Tested on Blazegraph by uploading sample triples from the question.